# Magento 2.1.1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: magento2, checkout, api, payment, guest-checkout

Magento 2.1.1.

I couldnot place order and continue receiving message "An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again." upon placing order.
I got this error on console "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)".

The POST url is => 
http://example.com/rest/default/V1/guest-carts/7d2013516903be5efea72e25f301d00c/payment-information

SOAP Api is installed.
Payment method is Cash on delivery

I don't find any issues on log.

Comment: Finally I figured out the problem. I have skipped City field on checkout because we don't need city on address. 
Upon enabling the city field, it worked.